# How to determine amount of bytes in VARCHAR field value?

Tags: mysql, varchar

I have a mysql field with datatype VARCHAR(5) with utf encoding. If I understand correctly field values can hold up to 5 characters and since I'm using utf-8 encoding, a max of 20+1 bytes.

Is there any way I can determine how much space a field value is taking up?

For example I expect the following to take up more than 5 bytes

```
رروحي
```

But for this to take up exactly 5 bytes

```
hello
```

And for this to take up more than 5 bytes

```
分別以後才
```

Comment: It doesn't matter. A `VARCHAR(5)` field can always contain up to five characters, no matter how many bytes those characters require.

Comment: @duskwuff, but the OP wants to *know* how much it takes, not to make sure it fits, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, mysql has `length` and `char_length` functions, so pick the one you need. Obviously, one is supposed to return length in bytes, the other — in characters.

If you want to find it out before it gets to the server side, you need to mention the programming language you use.

Comment: I don't think this is enough. For example, in latin Hello we know that it is 5 characters length by eye counting, but Do you know how to tell هلا length? It seems to be 3 but who knows?

Comment: Try `select length('هلا'), char_length('هلا');`